# Reading a binary file into a textblock

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to read an exe or any binary file contents into a textblock in C#. I am having the following code, but when I start reading the file the application gets stuck. My code is given below:

```
using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(FPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int size = 0;

    while ((size = fs1.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
    {
        Console.Write("[" + buf.Length + "/" + size + "]");
        textBox.Text += encoding.default.getstring(buf)
    }
}
```

Kindly guide me how can I solve this problem.

Comment: How do you mean 'Stuck'?

Comment: means the UI get hangs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read the whole file, you can use [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx).

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FPath);
textBox.Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

When you read chunks, those might not represent a full decodable string: sometimes characters need more than one byte and those might end up in different chunks.

Comment: Just a thought, but when reading in one go, you could use `File.ReadAllText` directly. `textBox.Text = File.ReadAllText("FPath", Encoding.Default); `

Comment: About the chunk problem, I'd imagine that there is a solution for that. Do you know if, and if so, what it is? - Never mind, found this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.decoder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: what if the file size is large??

Comment: @user3069453 - define "large". Do you really want GBs of text in that textbox?

Comment: @HansKesting maximum of 15MB

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of StreamWriter class of System.IO..
Here is a sample..

```
using( StreamReader sr = new StreamReader( FPath ) )
    {
        textBox.Text = sr.ReadToEnd( );
    }
```